# What's the difference between "pragma: no-cache" and "expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT" in HTTP headers?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers

There are some headers to indicate no-cache, for example, cache-control, pragma, expires.

When using expires for no-cache, set arbitrary past date such as Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT, and to set this, a browser won't cache the page.

reference: [Any significance to Google's "expires" date being Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487093/any-significance-to-googles-expires-date-being-fri-01-jan-1990-000000-gmt)

Then, I don't know the difference between them.

I think if set "pragma: no-cache" or "cache-control: no-cache", don't need "expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT".

Would you please ask me the difference between them?

*This image is an example in YouTube Music:*

[image: Here is an example in YouTube Music.]

Comment: Sure, it's technically redundant, but not all browsers/proxies may support "cache-control" or "pragma" headers. I'm pretty sure only the Expires header was in the HTTP/1.0 spec, so really old browsers and proxy servers may have issues if you only use those headers. More info: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Thank you for teaching me, and for providing me with useful article links. I understood the difference.